# preserve the elements value in matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I have a text dataset with labels and images. The labels are 1-dimensional elements representing handwritten digits. `Dimension:(1010,)`. Images are 28*28 pixel size images.`Dimension:(1010, 784)`. After reading from text dataset I have following dataset `reformatData['data']` and `reformatData['target']` - which are respectively `[n_samples, n_features]` and `[n_samples]`.

Again, dimensions of these: `(1010, 784) (1010,)` when printed `reformatData`

Now I am trying to do binary classification and introduce digits into the matrix, which I try to do with the following function.

```
digits1=[8]
digits2=[1]


def read(digits):
    rows=28
    cols=28
    #lbl = array("b", reformatData['target'])
    lbl = reformatData['target']
    img=reformatData['data']
    #img = array("B", reformatData['data'])

    ind = [ k for k in xrange(len(lbl)) if lbl[k] in digits]
    images =  matrix(0, (len(ind), rows*cols))
    labels = matrix(0, (len(ind), 1))
    for i in xrange(len(ind)):
        images[i, :] = img[ ind[i]*rows*cols : (ind[i]+1)*rows*cols ]
        labels[i] = lbl[ind[i]]
    return images, labels

print read(digits=digits1)
```

Output

```
(<0x784 matrix, tc='i'>, <0x1 matrix, tc='i'>)
```

I expected:

```
(<1010x784 matrix, tc='i'>, <1010x1 matrix, tc='i'>)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: If you are attempting to supply the feature matrix and target vector to a classification algorithm in sklearn, it is unnecessary to concatenate the two. Unless I am misunderstanding your question

Comment: thats exactly I am trying to do.  i am not worried about matrix concatenation. My problem is how to introduce "digits" in that matrix so I can perform binary SVM classification: like here http://cvxopt.org/applications/svm/index.html

Comment: Perhaps I am still unclear what you are trying to do. Your feature matrix should be of size [n_samples, n_features] as you have clarified above and your target vector should be of size [n_samples, 1]. Each column of your feature matrix should pertain to the same indicial location of a respective pixel in each image of your training set. Each row would represent an individual training example (or image) in this case. Are we in agreement so far?

Comment: yes, rahlf23. Thanks for the second part. So to outline problem if I wanted to do digits 3 vs digit 6, how do I introduce that. If I do not have "digits" variable to manipulate as I defined above

Comment: The example via the link you shared is attempting to classify 0's and 1's, are you attempting to expand this example to more than just two classes?

Comment: No just two classes for now. That is where I got stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159624/discussion-between-rahlf23-and-lpt).

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` `where` for vectorized and quicker computation:

With rahfl23's array above:

```
np.where(s==6, 0, 1)
```

For the matrix:

```
np.where(images==6, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To map two digits for binary classification, modify your target vector via list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([6, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8] ) 

new = np.array([0 if i==6 else 1 for i in s])
```

Output:

```
[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1]
```

Comment: thanks rahlf23, it works for single array like lbl but not for the img. List comprehension will generates ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() if implemented

Comment: use `np.where` on the matrix. `np.where(images==6, 1, images)`